# Datatables data not applyed to table

Tags: database, laravel, datatables

I am making ajax request with data send to method which returns data from database. I do get response (checked under network) but it doesn't get inserted into the table for some reason. Here is my code:

```html
<table class="table table-hover" id="users-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Id_sport</th>
            <th>Id_league</th>
            <th>Id_user</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Created At</th>
            <th>Updated At</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#users-table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            "ajax": {
                url: "{!! route('get.leaderboardsData') !!}",
                dataSrc: "",
                data: { id_sport: "3" }
            },
            columns: [
                { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
                { data: 'id_sport', name: 'id_sport' },
                { data: 'id_league', name: 'id_league' },
                { data: 'id_user', name: 'id_user' },
                { data: 'points', name: 'points' },
                { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at' },
                { data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at' }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here is function that return data from database:

```php
public function leaderboardsData(Request $request)
{
    $sport_id = $request->get('id_sport');

    if($sport_id==="0")
    {
        $query = DB::table('scores');
        return DataTables::of($query)->toJson();
    }
    else
    {
        $query = DB::table('scores')->where('id_sport', '=',$sport_id);
        return DataTables::of($query)->toJson();
    }
}
```

I am developing in Laravel.

Comment: Try adding ->get() on the end of your DB::table('scores') and ->where()

Comment: @Joeri It deosn't help, I don't think it's problem with DB query as I do get date if I check under network and go under response, but I don't know why it doesn't show in table

Comment: try `DataTables::of($query)->make(true);`

Comment: @ChamaraAbeysekara Same, I do get data in response but it's not shown

Comment: why you add dataSrc?

Comment: you need put `<tbody></tbody>` assign `id` and later print table put append `id table`

Comment: @JinalSomaiya It was actually dataSrc, I removed it and it works now

Comment: what happen now working or not?

Comment: Yes it works now